# What's the difference between exec_start and start event in docker

Tags: docker

What is the difference between exec_start and start event in docker.
Also can anyone explain the order in which these events are triggered and in detailed manner

Comment: What have you tried to find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `start` event is emitted by `docker start`, which you either run yourself or is run automatically after you do `docker run` or `docker create`. See the diagram below:

[image: Docker events diagram]

I found a prototype of that diagram [here](https://gliderlabs.com/devlog/2015/docker-events-explained/). And even though on that page it's written, that `exec_start` is one of the events, which is not affected by container state, I was actually never successful with emitting `exec_start` in any other state, but `Running`.

After your container enters `Running` state, a command executes based on how `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are configured in your `Dockerfile`, emitting `exec_create` and then `exec_start`. If you are running your containers through `docker-compose`, those are being overridden by `entrypoint` and `command` instructions.

Also, when you execute `docker exec`, you emit an `exec_create` event and after that an `exec_start` event.

The bottom line is, you first start the container, emitting `start`, then you execute something in your running container and emit `exec_start`.